# Could you please explain the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> For all my boss notices what I do in the office, I might as well not be there.

I'm having problems translating this.

It is from Youtube exercises to test my vocab. It is given like gap completion with suggested answers:

________ my boss notices what I do in the office, I might as well not be there!

a) For all
b) Whenever
c) With regards to

In the end it turned out the correct option is A- *For all*.
Does this sentence make sense to a native speaker?

Comment: Where is it from? It looks incomplete. It helps if you explain your particular doubts.

Answer (score 1):

The most common version of this construction actually gets its own dictionary entry...

> **for all I know**  <sup>([MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/for-all-i-know))</sup>
> used for emphasizing that you do not know something
> *He could be a murderer for all I know.*

...where we could rephrase the example as *I know very little about the matter in hand. In fact, I know so little about him that I don't even know for sure that he's not a murderer*.

--

OP's specific example can be paraphrased as...

> *My boss notices very little of what I do in the office. In fact, he wouldn't notice any difference if I wasn't there*

Comment: Could even compress further: *Considering that my boss notices nothing about* what I do in the office, I might as well not be there.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I do appreciate your time and help!

Comment: I should perhaps point out that I struggled to come up with  a good paraphrasing that would work well for *both* these examples. It's okay for the MacMillan example to be paraphrased as *I **don't know** [whether he's a murderer or not]*, but we can't really say the OP example here corresponds to *My boss **doesn't notice anything at all** that I do in the office*. The boss obviously notices *some* things - just not very much! (which can be exaggerated so much that he wouldn't even realise one of his staff wasn't there! :)